# Numpy/matplot: How to plot First X% is in range Y%?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, statistics

Assume I have the following observations:

**1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100**

Now I want to make a **plot** how the observations are distributed percent wise:

- First 12.5% of the observations is <=1 (1 out of 8)
- First 50% of the observations is <=4 (4 out of 4)
- First 87.5% of the observations is <=7 (7 out of 8)
- First 100% of the observations is <=100 (8 out of 8)

My questions:

- How is such kind of plot called? (so max observation on y axis per percentile, percentile on x axis?). A kind of histogram?
- How can I create such kind of plot in Matplotlib/Numpy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what such a plot would be called (edit: it appears it's called a cumulative frequency plot, or something similar). However, it's easy to do.

Essentially, if you have sorted data, then the percentage of observations <= a value at index `i` is just `(i+1)/len(data)`. It's easy to create an x array using arange that satisfies this. So, for example:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100])
pylab.plot( np.arange(1,len(a)+1)/len(a), a,    # This part is required
            '-', drawstyle='steps' )            # This part is stylistic
```

Gives:

[image: plot output]

If you'd prefer your x axis go from 0 to 100 rather than 0 to

Note too that this works for your example data because it is already sorted. If you are using unsorted data, then sort it first, with `np.sort` for example:

```
c = np.random.randn(100)
c.sort()
pylab.plot( np.arange(1,len(c)+1)/len(c), c, '-', drawstyle='steps' )
```

[image: plot output]